# Keypress in jQuery: Press TAB inside TEXTAREA (when editing an existing text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I want to insert TAB characters inside a TEXTAREA, like this:

```
<textarea>{KEYPRESS-INSERTS-TAB-HERE}Hello World</textarea>
```

I can insert *before/after* the existing TEXTAREA text - and I can insert / *replace all text* in the TEXTAREA - but have not yet been able to insert *inside* the existing TEXTAREA text (by the cursor) in a simple way.

```
$('textarea:input').live('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Press TAB to append a string (keeps the original TEXTAREA text).
        $(this).append("TAB TAB TAB AFTER TEXTAREA TEXT");

        // Press TAB to append a string (keeps the original TEXTAREA text).
        $(this).focus().prepend("TAB TAB TAB BEFORE TEXTAREA TEXT");

        // Press TAB to replace a all text inside TEXTAREA.
        $(this).val("INSERT INTO TEXTAREA / REPLACE EXISTING TEXT");

    }
});
```

There is a "tabs in textarea" plug-in for jQuery (["Tabby"](http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html)) - but it's 254 code lines - I was hoping for just a few lines of code.

A few links that I studied: (again, I would prefer fewer code lines).

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=34452
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32317
http://pallieter.org/Projects/insertTab/

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: The link to Tabby died, but a GitHub repo is available: https://github.com/alanhogan/Tabby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was creating a AJAX powered simple IDE for myself so I can rapidly test out PHP snippets.

I remember stumbling upon the same problem, here's how I solved it:

```
$('#input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        var myValue = "\t";
        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
        this.focus();
        this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.scrollTop = scrollTop;

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

`#input` is the ID of the textarea.

The code is not completely mine, I found it on Google somewhere.

I've only tested it on FF 3.5 and IE7. It does not work on IE7 sadly.

Comment: I had to replace `keypress` with `keydown` to get this to work in Chrome.

Comment: Very good... way better than other examples that use tons of code! I had to replace the keypress as well... wondering if we could suffice with only keypress.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, manipulating the text inside textarea elements is not as simple as one might hope.  The reason that Tabby is larger than those simple snippets is that it works better.  It has better cross-browser compatibility and handles things like tabbing selections.

When minified, it's only about 5k.  I'd suggest using it.  You'll either have to discover and troubleshoot those same edge cases yourself anyway, or might not even know about them if users don't report them.

Comment: +1 Looking at the 'Tabby' code I don't see too much waste there, just the code needed to replicate code editor tab functionality and do it in way that is compatible across browsers.  I agree that you should refactor it using a minifier and use it.

Comment: +1 Dave, Yes, I realized that the seemingly simple task was quite challenging. I will consider Tabby should I need a browser compatible solution. Thanks. /Kristoffer  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, dealing with input field selections across the different browsers is an annoyance, especially as in IE there are a few methods that *look* like they should work but actually don't. (Notably, combining using `setEndPoint` then measuring `length`, which looks OK until the selection starts or ends in newlines.)

Here's a couple of utility functions I use to deal with input selections. It returns the value of the input split into bits that are before, inside and after the selection (with the selection counting as an empty string at the input focus position if it's not a selection). This makes it fairly simply to replace and insert content at the point you want, whilst taking care of the IE CRLF problem.

(There may be a jQuery that does something like this, but I have yet to meet one.)

```
// getPartitionedValue: for an input/textarea, return the value text, split into
// an array of [before-selection, selection, after-selection] strings.
//
function getPartitionedValue(input) {
    var value= input.value;
    var start= input.value.length;
    var end= start;
    if (input.selectionStart!==undefined) {
        start= input.selectionStart;
        end= input.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection!==undefined) {
        value= value.split('\r').join('');
        start=end= value.length;
        var range= document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.parentElement()===input) {
            var start= -range.moveStart('character', -10000000);
            var end= -range.moveEnd('character', -10000000);
            range.moveToElementText(input);
            var error= -range.moveStart('character', -10000000);
            start-= error;
            end-= error;
        }
    }
    return [
        value.substring(0, start),
        value.substring(start, end),
        value.substring(end)
    ];
}

// setPartitionedValue: set the value text and selected region in an input/
// textarea.
//
function setPartitionedValue(input, value) {
    var oldtop= input.scrollTop!==undefined? input.scrollTop : null;
    input.value= value.join('');
    input.focus();
    var start= value[0].length;
    var end= value[0].length+value[1].length;
    if (input.selectionStart!==undefined) {
        input.selectionStart= start;
        input.selectionEnd= end;
        if (oldtop!==null)
            input.scrollTop= oldtop;
    }
    else if (document.selection!==undefined) {
        var range= input.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', end);
        range.moveStart('character', start);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getPartitionedValue` gives an error in IE on the `range.moveToElementText(input);` line for `<input>` elements (it's fine for textareas).

Comment: You can fix this by replacing the offending line with `var inputRange = input.createTextRange(); range.moveToBookmark(inputRange.getBookmark());`

Answer (score 0):

btw, see also:
http://aspalliance.com/346_Tabbing_in_the_TextArea