# different caret position on firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, caret

To recreate the problem, please visit http://jsfiddle.net/BsJ6V/ and type any character right after the opening body tag (for example, `<body>h` if you type the h character).

An alert box will display the caret position. When you run it **in Firefox the caret position is 56**, when you run it **in IE it is 60**. Could you please what the matter is?

**EDIT**::
[**UPDATED LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/BsJ6V/1/).

Comment: i think in IE, the canvas is subracted by its scroll bar that why you get a difference of 4

Comment: please check the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/BsJ6V/1/

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because IE counts each line break within a textarea as two characters (CRLF, or `\r\n`) while Firefox counts it as a single LF (`\n`) character.

Your function won't get the right caret position in IE if there are leading line breaks. To see this, place the caret at the start of the textarea in your first jsFiddle example and press return a few time and trying typing in one of the empty lines. To fix this, you can use [a function I've posted before on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622818/ies-document-selection-createrange-doesnt-include-leading-or-trailing-blank-lin/3648244#3648244) or if you prefer a jQuery plug-in, I've created one for dealing with textarea selections: http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

**UPDATE**

Note that jQuery's `val()` method normalizes this difference in line breaks between browsers (unhelpfully, in my view, since the value that gets sent to the server isn't normalized) so that line breaks are always `\n`. Both my plug-in and your function return a caret position relative to the textarea's raw value property, not jQuery's normalized value, so if you are manipulating the value using the caret position, you need to use `$textarea[0].value` instead of `$textarea.val()`.

You can see this difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyR7J/2/