# Find position of cursor in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Why isn't this code working?

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/5db40.php

```
<form>
   <textarea></textarea>
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 9){

                     $("textarea").selectionStart.append("    ");
                     e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You have to press TAB on textarea

Problem is that it doesn't do/append four spaces and it does default browser action (switch to adress tab in Chrome)

Thoughts?

Comment: Observation: even Stack Overflow's `textarea`s, which generally contain code that is indented, don't allow tabs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing TAB key in text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box)

Comment: @genesis: I don't know exactly. I haven't tried to do it myself. But my comment was suggesting that maybe it isn't feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714830/selectionstart-end-with-textareas) question, try:

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var pos = $this[0].selectionStart;
            $this.val($this.val().substring(0, pos) + "    " + $this.val().substring(pos));
            $this.setCursorPosition(pos + 4);
        }
    });
});
```

And add the JQuery from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) post.

```
new function($) {
  $.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
      $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
      var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  }
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thats probably because `append` is not a javascript string function. Try the old `string = string + 'extra stuff';` approach.

Comment: but this appends these spaces at the end. I want it to the actual position of pointer

Comment: still switching to my address bar tsandbox.phpcode.eu/g/81281.php

Comment: Thats because the javascript had an error. Please see the corrections.

Comment: works, but not as I wanted. It appends tab to the end, not to actual pointer position

Comment: When you had `append` in your post I assumed thats what you wanted. In either case the updated code will work in chrome and firefox, but not IE. Hope it helps

Comment: The code for obtaining the caret position won't work in IE < 9. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For manipulating textarea selections and caret positions in jQuery, I recommend using [my jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) for doing this, which work in all major browsers and provides methods for getting and setting the caret/selection position, inserting content at the caret position and more. The code you want would be:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).replaceSelectedText("    ");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Keypress in jQuery: Press TAB inside TEXTAREA (when editing an existing text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738808/keypress-in-jquery-press-tab-inside-textarea-when-editing-an-existing-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i'm damn sure it will work.

```
<form> 
   <textarea></textarea> 
</form> 
<script> 
$(function(){ 
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e){ 
        if (e.which == 9){ 

                     $("textarea").append("    "); 
                     return false;
        } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

I just simply changed the word "keyCode" to "which", 'cause the word keyCode is derived from jquery ui.

Comment: Kindly, check my code again, i did a little modification again, it's working fine for me in all browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
range.collapse(true);
range.moveEnd('character', pos);
range.moveStart('character', pos);
range.select();
```

This ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzumX/16/)) was the best I could manage, but I can't get it working on Firefox or Chrome. If somebody manages to get the button press select text in textarea with Chrome working, feel free to let me know.